# Draggable element on iOS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, drag

I'm trying to make a mini draggable element that will show items in a container, that way the user can drag the items to view the other items on the right when when dragging.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

When the user drags it, it should reveal the other boxes on the right (10, 11, 12, 13, etc...) with the white box as the container, but my code seems to make it drag in the reverse direction, for example, if the user drags in right direction, the boxes go left direction and left direction goes the right direction.

When dragging into the left direction:

[image]

When dragging into the right direction:

[image]

This is my code:

```
var firstTouch;
$('.scroll-wrapper').bind('touchstart touchmove', function(event)
{
    if(event.type == 'touchstart')
    {
        firstTouch = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;  
    }

    var scrollAmount = firstTouch - event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

    $(this).css('left', scrollAmount);
});
```

What I would like to also have is to stop the boxes from scrolling when it has reached the end of the container if the box 0 is at the edge of the left then it should not be able to drag into the left direction anymore except to be dragged in the right direction, same goes for the last box should not continue to drag.

How can I accomplish this? I do not want to include any mobile plugins (jQuery, Sencha, etc).

EDIT:

My source:

```
.scroll-area {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: visible; 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1; 
}

.scroll-area .scroll-wrapper {
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; 
}

.scroll-area .scroll-wrapper .item {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #F00;
    margin: 2px;    
}

<div class="scroll-area">
    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
        <div class="item">0</div>
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
        <div class="item">10</div>
        <div class="item">11</div>
        <div class="item">12</div>
        <div class="item">13</div>
        <div class="item">14</div>
        <div class="item">15</div>
        <div class="item">16</div>
        <div class="item">17</div>
        <div class="item">18</div>
        <div class="item">19</div>
        <div class="item">20</div>
        <div class="item">21</div>
        <div class="item">22</div>
        <div class="item">23</div>
        <div class="item">24</div>
        <div class="item">25</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just have your sign reversed.  Then add a check to see if the scroll is over the maximum scroll value (content width - display area width), and set it to maximum if it does.  The lower threshold is easier (0).

Edit: Just realized you probably want to add your current position to your scroll offset.  Example edited.

```
var firstTouch;
var drag = 0;
var startPos = 0;

// Maximum scroll value to (swiping left), minimum is 0
var maxScroll = $('.scroll-wrapper').outerWidth() - $('.scroll-wrapper').parent().innerWidth();

$('.scroll-area').on('touchstart touchmove', '.scroll-wrapper', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.type == 'touchstart') {
        firstTouch = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        startPos = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
        if (isNaN(startPos)) {
            startPos = 0;
        }
    }

    // current - first, not the other way around
    // This is negative for swiping left
    var scrollAmount = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX - firstTouch;

    var offset = startPos + scrollAmount;


    if (-offset > maxScroll) {
        offset = -maxScroll;
    } else if (offset > 0) {
        offset = 0;
    }
    $(this).css('left', offset);

});
```

Click version in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/Gcgpg/6/

Comment: Nothing gets moved? When I remove `if(scrollAmount < 0) {` it will move to the right direction, but not the left.

Comment: I just edited the example.  Try that.  I don't have a mobile at the moment to test on.

Comment: I had my signs reversed, and I realized you need to log the start position of the element too.  I made a click based mockup here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/Gcgpg/2/  Dealing with clicks is different, so you can ignore some of my other junk in that example, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't scroll anything, just won't move at all. I don't see any errors being thrown in the Safari console log.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird.  Give it a try in firefox.  It's just a hacked example.  The principles should work with touch events in mobile safari.

Comment: Ah, I forgot, WebKit returns `auto` instead of 0 for `left`, which is messing up the `startPos`.  Example fixed.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. I updated my post for the code and CSS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8691/discussion-between-jeff-b-and-burning-the-codeigniter)